# Random process & probability problem met in wireless communication

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

A random process r obeys the following distribution:

$p(r,ṙ)=rb_0\exp(−\frac{r^2}{2b_0})\sqrt{2πb_2}exp(−\frac{\dot{r}^2}{2b_2})$, where $\dot{r}$ is the derivative of r in the time domain.

You can see that r ranges from 0 to infinity. r(t) is a realization of the random process during time T. What I want to calculate is, during 0 to T, what is the probability that we can find a time period with length τ such that, during this τ time period, the value of r is always larger than a threshold η?

Let me know if there is something not clear in the question. This problem is difficult, but it does not seem to be not solvable. At least Monte Carlo algorithm can be used. And a similar version of this problem has been solved in the 1940s.

It would be great if you can help me come up with some idea of it.

Comment: You should add a link to the 1940s problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the advice. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6767541.  The 1948 paper by S.O. Rice, in the 4th section, he used the same distribution to calculate another statistic, the level cross rate.

Comment: Your joint density does not seem to determine a process uniquely, so the question is not clear.

Comment: What you can deduce from the expression is the EXPECTED NUMBER of zero crossings of the process in the interval [0,T]. Not surprisingly (in view of the reference you quote) this is attached to the name of Rice (and Kac). Just google "Kac-Rice formula".

Comment: Thanks Ofer for your comment. Yes, the Kac-Rice formula can calculate the expected number of zero crossings of the process in the interval [0,T]. But I am not clear, since I am calculating just a probability, why do I need the process to be unique. :)

Comment: @Vinnie because different processes will give different probabilities.

Comment: I think your opinion is to the point. But for this question, maybe I am correct, but why this  distribution cannot determine a unique random process